# Позиционирование относительно родителя с сохранением выделенного места

Tags: html, css

Есть div. Внутри него надо отпозиционировать другие 2 divа относительно правого края. Внутренние "распирают" внешний из-за полей. Суть в том, чтобы сохранить эти поля. 
Вот так надо расположить элементы:

[image: http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/5000/34425538.1/0_d455b_f9d7cc50_L.jpg]

Comment: Проблема была решена с помощью float:right у дочерних элементов и overflow:auto у родителя. http://s3.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2014/01/834cb70535bdca38c3d84bb74c30576e.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После редактирования вопрос стал ещё более непонятен.

Но может здесь вас что-то заинтересует?
http://jsfiddle.net/tF85t/1/

Answer (score 0):

как вариант, банально использовать position: absolute, но возможно я не понял ваш вопрос
http://jsfiddle.net/tF85t/

Comment: если бы все было так просто. Абсолют "удаляет" элемент со страницы. То есть отпозиционировать то его можно, но с тем что он место занимает, никто "считаться" не будет

Comment: покажите ваш сайт или реальный пример, или на jsfiddle выложите код. А то с этими черными рамками возиться не стоит. Нужно реальную проблему разбирать

Comment: так а в этом: http://jsfiddle.net/tF85t/1/ варианте что вас не устраивает?

Comment: не сразу увидел ваш ответ. Вот и всё